# gunicorn + Flask on Heroku, run seveal apps

Tags: python, flask, heroku, gunicorn

i am trying run frontend and backend apps on one server on Heroku.

```
web: gunicorn app.app_back:app
web: gunicorn app.app:app
```

But this example execute only the last app. Can i run several apps on Heroku? And do it without Nginx.

Comment: Why don't you want to use nginx?

Comment: I think you can only run 1 per dyno. I have a 3 part app (website, and 2 api) that run with flask that I'm running on heroku, but using a dockerfile. You can check out the dockerfile and heroku.yml [here](https://github.com/Riverside-Healthcare/extract_management), and the [app](https://demo.extract.management).